# if field is empty, return all results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working at a search script at the moment, but I have a little problem. I'm using the following query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boeken WHERE 
             titel LIKE '%".$titel."%' AND 
             categorie_id = '".$categorie."' AND 
             auteurs LIKE '%".$auteurs."%' AND 
             jaar_copyright = '".$jaar_copyright."' 
             AND ontwerp_groep = '".$ontwerp_groep."'");
```

For example, when I search for `'categorie_id' = '5'`, and leave the other fiels empty, I want to get every row that has categorie_id = 5. No matter what the other fields are.

What it does is the following: I get every row that has categorie_id = 5, but where the title is empty, where the 'jaar_copyright' is empty, etc. etc.

How can I fix this the way I want?

Comment: Are you saying that the results have `titel` and `jaar_copyright` as empty, but they shouldn't be? Or that you only want results that don't have anything for these fields in the database?

Comment: What's the values of `$titel`, `$jaar_copyrigh`...?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to post that. I post 'categorie_id' = 5, and I leave all the other field empty. What the query does is giving the results back of 'categorie_id' = 5, and all the other fiels MUST be empty. (Difficult for me to explain it clear, hope you understand it this way.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysql or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. On the subject, varying values shouldn't be interpolated directly into the statement; instead, use prepared statement parameters, the same as you'd create parameters when defining a function.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "empty"? `NULL`? The empty string?

Comment: What do you mean with 'new code should use mysql'? This is MySql? Anyway, with empty I mean an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM boeken WHERE";
    $n = 0;
    $makeAnd = "";

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if($value != '' && $value != 'submit'){
            if($n != 0){$makeAnd = " AND";}
            if(!is_numeric($value)){
            $query .= "$makeAnd `$key` LIKE '%$value%'";
        } else {
            $query .= "$makeAnd `$key` = '$value'";
        }
            $n++;
        }

    }

    print $query;


?>
```

In this way you can filter out empty values. If other values are posted to $_POST make sure to filter them out in the "if($value !=" part.

Comment: @BlueCola note that this by using this code you are making your site vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Just realized that if someone searches 'title' with '101' it will return a '=' instead of LIKE. A way to solve this, would be to use prefixes in your values. e.g. name="desc_title". By using strpos() and say a switch case, you can generate a query categorized in a similar way as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what field is set in code, and then only add that part to your query. for instance:

```
if(isset($_POST['categorie_id'])){
        $where = " categorie_id = '".$categorie."' ";
}elseif(...){
  ....
}
```

Well, you get the point, you can make it a bit neater probably, depending on the format of your form/POST etc, but that's the idea. Just figure out WHAT you know, and then push it in the SQL.

I'm at work, so no long stories possible, but you should be able to figure it out with this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$item){
    if($value != ''){
        $yourField = $key;
        $yourValue = $item;
    }
}

//PERFORM SANITY CHECKS!
//MAYBE USE PDO etc? (but that's another thing)
//SAVE them in 2 new variables used below:

$query  = "SELECT * FROM boeken WHERE `$sanitizedField` = '$sanitizedValue'";
```

Comment: Yes, I had considered this solution earlier. But when you get to many fields, you have like 15 if else state's. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Make an array of all the fields, and do like Nanne said going `foreach` of them.

Comment: If you put them in your POST intelligently you could find yourself a key and value from the post, so you would just add a ` WHERE $_POST['key'] = $_POST['value']` ofcourse. But mind you, you'll just have some sort of framework here: you should obviously take care of injections, wrong values etc etc, but for the first steps you could use that?

Comment: @Nanne So, you recommend a foreach as well?

Comment: Well, if you're sure that only 1 field is added as you seem to imply in your comment, you don't need to do that: just pick your 1 field from the post, and add that. I suggested to just not add the empty values to your POST, so there would be nothing to foreach over. If that's not an option, you could foreach over your POST, find the one item with a value, and make a WHERE statement of that. Basically, the real tip is: find your WHERE in code, add it to the query, and then run it.

Comment: Nanne, I see that you're dutch. Could we have a talk in the chat?

Comment: sorry, signing off for today :)

Comment: Ok, hope that you can help me a bit more. It's not only about the field categorie_id. I want that whatever field I leave blank in the form, is not added to the query, like you said. But I'm searching for the most dynamic solution to acomplish that. (I dont want 10 if/else statements). How could I do it with an foreach?

Answer (score 0):

For each criteria, you need to add a second evaluation for a blank parameter value:

`(categorie_id = '".$categorie."' OR '".$categorie."' = '') AND ...`

This way you cover both cases of an empty or a populated parameter.

**EDIT:**

Sample query as it would appear in SQL.

Assume you pass in a $categorie of `5` and no other parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM boeken WHERE 
             (titel LIKE '%%' OR '' = '' )AND 
             (categorie_id = '5' OR '5' = '') AND 
             (auteurs LIKE '%%' OR '' = '') AND 
...
```

If they get passed in as `NULL` then do a `NULL` comparison instead of an empty string comparison.

Comment: What does this sql exactly? I don't understand what the second OR does.

Comment: You are checking for if the category is equal to your passed parameter, OR the passed parameter is blank.  Only one of those will be true, but it will allow you to limit your results as needed based on parameters without changing the query each time.

Comment: Ok, but let's assume that the passed parameter: $categorie is empty. What will the query do with it? Search for the result where $categorie ie empty? Or show all results, ignoring the categorie_id field?

Comment: Show all results ignoring that field.  Note that the `OR` is comparing the PARAMETER to an empty string, not the categorie_id field.  So, either where the categorie_id is equal to the parameter OR the parameter is blank.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm feeling really stupid right now, because I still don't understand. Can you give my the full query with your solution? Maybe I see how it works then.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this. But for me it look likes: "if the field titel is empty, replace the field with empty". I can't really see what you're changing.

Comment: This doesn't work: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.

Comment: I apologize that you don't understand the concept but I'm not putting any more time into trying to explain it to you.

Comment: Are you sure it should work? Someone else already de-voted your answer to -1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5690/discussion-between-bluecola-and-jnk)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build a query based on vars? That way they're not included in the query unless the var is populated. I don't know what your variables like $titel actually are, so I just say if they're not blank. This should obviously be set towhatever is applicable. Not null, isset, etc. and always escape with something like mysql_real_escape_string()

```
$titel_where = "";
if($titel != '')
    $title_where = "AND titel LIKE '%".$titel."%'";

$auteurs_where = "";
if($auteurs_where != "")
   $auteurs_where = "AND auteurs LIKE '%".$auteurs."%'";

$jaar_copyright_where = "";
if($jaar_copyright != '')
    $jaar_copyright_where = "AND jaar_copyright = '".$jaar_copyright."'";

$ontwerp_groep_where = "";
if($ontwerp_groep != '')
    $ontwerp_groep_where = "AND ontwerp_groep = '".$ontwerp_groep."'";

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boeken WHERE 
             categorie_id = '".$categorie."' 
             $titel_where
             $auteurs_where  
             $jaar_copyright_where  
             $ontwerp_groep_where
             ");
```

Comment: This could by a solution, but I want it dynamic, so i don't have 10 if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boeken WHERE 
             ( '".$categorie."' = 5 AND
               categorie_id = 5
             ) OR
             ( titel LIKE '%".$titel."%' AND 
               categorie_id = '".$categorie."' AND 
               auteurs LIKE '%".$auteurs."%' AND 
               jaar_copyright = '".$jaar_copyright."' AND
               ontwerp_groep = '".$ontwerp_groep."'
             )");
```

Comment: Note: the categorie_id = 5, was just an example. It could be that I only post the field 'titel' = abcdef, and leave all the other fields blank. Than I want to show all the row's with titel = abcdef , no matter what the categorie_id, auteurs, etc. fields are.

Comment: In that case, it would be easier to make your PHP code construct different variation of the query.